# how to check if a nested object property is undefined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties, undefined

I have a Javascript object and I'm struggling mightly to check in a loop if `postsome` is undefined.

Here is my object:

```
var indices = [{
    "indexAB": [{
        "postsome": [
            "keyword_abc",
            "keyword_def"
         ]
       }]
    },{
    "indexA": [{
        "postsome": [
            "keyword_abc"
        ]
      }]
    }
 ]
```

Problem is, I can't reference `indexA`,`indexAB` or `postsome` directly. All will be variables. This is what I'm trying:

```
// passed parameter
var doc._id = "postsome";

// mapping priv
// "indices": [
//    {"name":"indexA","fields":["findMeA"]},
//    {"name":"indexAB", "fields":["findMeA","findMeB"]}
//    ],

for (var i = 0, l = indices.length; i < l; i += 1) {

  var index = priv.indices[i];
      index_name = index["name"]; // indexAB or indexA

  // I can't reference indexAB directly 
  if ( indices[i].indexAB !== undefined && indices[i].indexAB.length  >  0 )          {
      console.log( indices[i].indexAB );
      console.log( indices[i].indexAB[0][doc._id] );

      if (indices[i].indexAB[0][doc._id] !== undefined) {
        console.log("gotcha");
        trigger = true;
      }
    }
}
```

So when I use `indexAB` hardcoded it works, but I need to loop through the values ('indexA' and 'indexAB' instea).

**Question:**
Is there any way to replace `.indexAB[0]` with a variable? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: `var prop = 'indexAB'; indices[i][prop]`... this has been asked *so* many times before.

Comment: let me try. I can't believe it's that easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use bracket notation, the exact same way you do with `[doc._id]`.

```
if (indices[i][index_name] !== undefined && indices[i][index_name].length > 0)
```

Bracket notation and dot notation are interchangable, so these two lines are equivalent:

```
indices.foo
indices["foo"]
```

If you need to use a variable, however, `indices.varName` would translate to `indices["varName"]`, so you must use bracket notation to ensure that it uses the variable value instead of the variable name as a string.